How do I optimize by PRIMARY KEY when creating a table?
I am trying to create a table in Cassandra and my query is the following:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace.user (
    uid text,
    userjson text,
    email text,
    username text,
    dob text,
    number text,
    PRIMARY KEY ()
)

Most likely I will be querying this table via uid (unique) to pull userjson. How would I optimize by the PRIMARY KEY? What would I add in the PRIMARY KEY? Is it just uid?
I haven't tried anything yet.

Yes, as long as you can guarrantee uid is unique and only uid is always queried, setting it as the only partition key for primary key would be the recommended approach as it's effcient to read/write row based on the primary key index. You can learn more about choosing the right primary key configuration here

In Cassandra, you would model your data based on the application queries.
In your case where you application will be retrieving the data by uid, you are correct in that you need to partition by uid:
CREATE TABLE users_by_uid
    uid text,
    userjson text,
    email text,
    username text,
    dob text,
    number text,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)

As a side note, you can name tables whatever you want but the best practice is to name it by (1) its contents, (2) by how it is partitioned. In the case above, it is a table of users and partitioned by_uid.
To expand it a bit further, if the application needs to retrieve users based on their email, then the table will be modeled in this way:
CREATE TABLE users_by_email
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
)

Similarly if the application needs to retrieve users based on their username:
CREATE TABLE users_by_username
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
)

All these three tables are effectively the same except that the data is organised by how the application will query them, with data duplicated in three tables but optimised for application reads. We are sacrificing disk space (data duplication) for performance (optimised reads) because storage is cheap. Cheers!
